# Is there a minimum file size that is recommended for data compression?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, compression

Users can send a message from a Flash based app to a friend via PHP. The message can be up to 3000 characters long. Should I use a compression method (e.g. ByteArray) to send the message string or does it make no sense because it's too small?

Answer (score 0):

3000 bytes is more than enough to see a *potential* benefit from compression.  How effective it will be, though, depends on the content of the message.  Natural-language text (particularly if using an 8-bit encoding like ISO-8859-1, or even UTF-8) would almost certainly compress well; an image, on the other hand, probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend performing some benchmarks to determine the average size of the message being sent. Just because the message's maximum size is 3000 characters doesn't mean it will always be that long. It is entirely possible that implementing compression on messages that are under a couple hundred bytes will take up more space than simply sending them as is.